# In Outlook 2010, How do I add holidays to the non-default calendar?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar

At my workplace (I think it's connected to Cloud-365 if that's relevant) I'm working with Outlook 2010.

Under 'My Calendars' I created a new calendar, in addition to the default 'Calendar' I already have there.
I want to import the local holidays to this new calendar, same way as I imported them to my default calendar. However, I can't seem to find a way.
Whenever I import the holidays it only adds them to the default calendar.

How can I add them to the other calendar as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How do I add holidays to the non-default calendar?

Solution 1: Copy them from the default calendar

- Open the first calendar
- Switch to  category view
- Select holidays category
- Ctrl C to copy
- Switch to new calendar
- Ctrl V to paste

Solution 2: Toggle default calendar

- Set new calendar as the default calendar
- Add the holidays
- Set old calendar as the default calendar

Comment: Copy-pasting worked perfectly. Thanks.